# How to make snap operator not use transplate?

Tags: python, mesh, snapping, bmesh, vector-mapping

Just appoint two vertices\edges\face, The snap operator autocomplete. I have achieved the vertices mode, Calculate the translation matrix from vertex1 to vertex2, Then translate the object1's location, But I don't know how to deal with edges and faces.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import sys
from bpy.types import Gizmo, GizmoGroup, Operator
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix
import global_var as glv

class ARCHIPACK_OT_snap_select(Operator):
    bl_idname = "archipack.snap_select"
    bl_label = "xxxxx"
    bl_description = "xxxxxxxxx"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    widget = None
    act_name = None
    sles = []
    select_flag = 'first'
    type = None
    snap_obj = None
    location = None
    bm = None
    geom = None
    
    def _exit(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
        self.widget = None
        
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")
        for o in self.sels:
            if o.name == self.act_name:
                self.select_object(context, o, True)
            else:
                self.select_object(context, o, False)

        self.act_name = None
        self.sles = []
        self.select_flag = 'first'
        self.type = None
        self.snap_obj = None
        self.location = None
        self.bm = None
        self.geom = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        # if event.type != 'MOUSEMOVE':
        #     print(event.ctrl, event.shift, event.alt, event.type, event.value)
        
        context.area.tag_redraw()

        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            mval = Vector((event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y))
            # get catch element
            # element owner(snap_obj.data: objects list), last mouse location, mouse location, element type(vert/edge/face), object bmesh, element bmesh
            self.widget.snap_obj, prevloc, self.widget.location, self.widget.type, self.widget.bm, self.widget.geom, len = snap_utilities(
                    self.widget.sctx,
                    None,
                    mval,
                    increment=self.widget.incremental)

        if event.value == 'PRESS':
            if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
                if self.select_flag == 'first':
                    if self.widget.type not in ['VERT', 'EDGE', 'FACE']:
                        self.report({'WARNING'}, "请选择构件顶点边面进行吸附！")
                    else:
                        self.select_flag = 'second'
                        self.type = self.widget.type
                        self.snap_obj = self.widget.snap_obj
                        self.location = self.widget.location
                        self.bm = self.widget.bm
                        self.geom = self.widget.geom

                elif self.select_flag == 'second':
                    if self.widget.type != self.type:
                        mes = ''
                        if self.type == 'VERT':
                            mes = '顶点'
                        elif self.type == 'EDGE':
                            mes = '边'
                        else:
                            mes = '面'
                        self.report({'WARNING'}, "请选择构件%s进行吸附！"%mes)
                    elif self.snap_obj.data[0].name == self.widget.snap_obj.data[0].name:
                        self.report({'WARNING'}, "请选择不同构件进行吸附！")
                    else:
                        self.snap_handler(context)
                        self._exit(context)
                        return {'FINISHED'}

            elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
                self._exit(context)
                return {'FINISHED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def snap_handler(self, context):
        if self.type == 'VERT':
            self.snap_vert(context)
        elif self.type == 'EDGE':
            self.snap_edge(context)
        elif self.type == 'FACE':
            self.snap_face(context)

    def snap_vert(self, context):
        o_base = self.snap_obj.data[0]
        o_trans = self.widget.snap_obj.data[0]

        pp0 = o_trans.matrix_world @ self.widget.geom.co - o_base.matrix_world @ self.geom.co
        pp1 = o_trans.matrix_world @ self.widget.geom.co - self.location
        trans = Matrix.Translation(pp1)
        o_trans.location = o_trans.location - pp0 @ trans

    def snap_edge(self, context):
        pass
        
    def snap_face(self, context):
        pass

    def draw_callback(self):
        self.widget.draw_point_and_elem()

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.space_data.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            
            # get catch service
            widget = glv.get_value('snap_gizmo')
            if not widget:
                self.report({'WARNING'}, "自动捕捉服务获取失败！")
                return {'CANCELLED'}

            self.widget = widget
            self.sels = context.selected_objects
            if context.active_object:
                self.act_name = context.active_object.name
            
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="SELECT")

            op = bpy.ops.object.mode_set
            if not op.poll():
                self.report({'WARNING'}, "缺少可吸附构件！")
                return {'CANCELLED'}

            op(mode='EDIT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(self.draw_callback, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')

            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "Active space must be View3d")
            return {'CANCELLED'}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code please so we know what you've tried

Comment: I have added my code. Unfortunately, the catch module involves too many other modules, I can't list them. @Psyonic

Comment: The function of the code is to enter the editing mode, select all objects, then select a vertex, edge or face of two of them, transform the second object, and automatically snap to the first object